# Почему Черномор?

Tags: литература

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему злобного колдуна в "Руслане и Людмиле" зовут Черномор? При чем тут Черное море?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вот не доказано, что там именно "море", а не мор. ))) Представляете, колдун Черный Мор?! Жуть...

Хотя, думаю, все проще. Черномор встречается не только в "Руслане и Людмиле". Сравните с со сказкой о царе Салтане. Остров Буян имеет прототип (один из называемых) в Черном море. Это остров Березань чуть западнее Крыма. Где-то там должно быть и "царство славного Салтана", с которым этот самый Черномор связан. Видимо, те края прочно ассоциировались в народном сознании с чем-то сказочным, волшебным.

Есть, правда, мнение, что это имя-назвние впервые фиксируется именно у Пушкина, в русских же былинах и сказках фигурирует некий Черногор. Тут я, не зная досконально источники, не берусь быть судией, но сам по себе вариант представляется несколько сомнительным. Пушкин никогда не конструировал имена подобым образом (Фарлаф - исключение, имеющее своё объяснение в возможной неточной транскрипции имен исторических персонажей). Так что эту идею оставляю на совести авторов.

Comment: Интересно! А мне попадалась информация, что прототип Буяна находится где-то в Балтийском море!

Comment: Да, на Балтике даже два "прототипа"  находят. И ещё один - на озере где-то в Пруссии. Плюс еще один - в Помории. Это понятно, в любом уважающем себя восточном городе вам покажут "самую настоящую" могилу Ходжи Насреддина. Но мне лично черноморская версия кажется более аргументированной по самому анализу текста. Все прочие, например, не учитывают склонность к контрабанде тамошних корабельщиков, приторговывающих "неуказанным товаром". Это колорит черноморский, не балтийский.